# AMD drivers are outdated

Tags: ati, fglrx

I have a Acer Aspire V5-552G laptop that comes with two AMD graphics cards(APU + a dedicated one). I have installed the proprietary fglrx-updates drivers, but the drivers are old. They don't even include the switch graphics option to switch between the two graphics cards. What can I do to get the new amd omega drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how old your Ubuntu installation is, but in just this past year, Ubuntu has radically changed how it handles device drivers, and things have gotten SO GOOD I've taken to uninstalling the proprietary drivers I'd installed, as now Ubuntu often runs my graphics better this way.  I recommend you try uninstalling your AMD drivers (either by command line or using the Synaptic Package Manager), and then if things don't improve, then returning to the System Settings, "additional drivers" icon to load new AMD drivers.

Before posting this "answer" I bothered to look up your laptop and it seems that some or all of that model had a touch screen.  I have Ubuntu on a rather old and heavy tablet and it operates it just fine without having installed any special drivers.

Please clarify what functionality you aren't seeing.  As for switching between the two monitors, that's handled in the System Settings under "Displays".

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.10 fresh installed

Comment: Interesting.  Are you saying you had not made any effort to try using the "Additional Drivers" utility, and yet you are saying the drivers are out of date?  Or are you saying you did try that, and the ones you found were out of date?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My laptop dosen't have a touch.  The functionality I want is to switch between my APU and GPU not between monitors.I know that new versions of amd drivers have such option. That is the only reason I want these drivers. If the default open source drivers ca do that then I will use them.

Comment: I made the effort of installing the additional drivers and they were outdated.

Comment: I am going to look into this matter a little more on your behalf, but please confirm for me, what you essentially want to do is turn off the internal default graphics so that your laptop displays only through its add on graphics card?  If that's right I may already know the answer, but I'm going to look into alternative means as my solution might appear to be a kludge.

Comment: Sort of... The amd windows drivers are able to use the APU on software that dosen't require graphics power such as firefox and libreoffice and to use the gpu on steam am games, that is what I want to do.To be able to use them both at the same time but for different software.

Comment: I think I know how to do what you want to do, and it looks to me like my first assumption was correct.  The displays icon under settings permits you to assign one monitor as primary, preferably the internal one.  From there you can certainly choose to run STEAM only one one display while retaining system control on the other monitor.  

The only part of this I am unsure of regards which graphics chipset is necessarily operating each display, but I would tend to assume the integrated one would by default operate the integrated display.

Comment: No, I only have one monitor(the laptop build in monitor). I have two graphics cards. Here I found a picture of what I'm trying do.http://digitizor.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/catalyst.jpeg

Comment: oic.  Thanks for explaining.  I can see how you might be frustrated by drivers which do not emulate functions like that if you had grown to expect them from Windows.  I suspect though that this type of feature is not something Ubuntu developers would have thought to try to emulate for the simple reason that most laptops only have one graphics chipset, and no mode to switch between them.  Desktops with more than one gpu typically have one display for each, or their sole monitor connected to only one gpu.  I will keep looking, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: I just read an article about this feature and it seems to think your add-in graphics card is made by nvidia.  If so, please try OTHER non-open-source drivers until you find one which does what you want.  I have been through this.  The latest revision is not always the most capable.